# Oracle 11G usable space

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

So I have an Oracle 11G instance running on a Linux server. How do I verify how much more data can the database contain?

The question has a twist.

I was running a load-test on the application. Database server started running out of free space in one of /u0X/ filesystems (where the database itself lies). It had only 93MB free left out of 40GB. I instructed my app to delete most of its data on the database and it did. However free space on /u0X/ remained the same -- 93MB.

asktom explained that once data is deleted it is not marked as 'free space' per-se and 'free-space' does not increase on the tablespace. Instead database reuses already occupied BUT marked for deletion space (or smth like that)

So again... How do I keep an eye on how much more data can my database contain? How do I know whether I should consider asking application to purge its data again before it starts hurling in logs with exceptions and returning HTTP:500s?

**EDIT:** a reply to Cyrille's answer

```
TABLESPACE_NAME                MEGS_ALLOC  MEGS_FREE  MEGS_USED   PCT_FREE   PCT_USED        MAX
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
APP01                               34920         27      34893          0        100      65536
SIGNSERVER                             10          7          3         70         30      32768
SYSAUX                               1120         63       1057          6         94      32768
SYSTEM                               4290          1       4289          0        100      32768
TEMP                                 1345       1343          2        100          0      32768
UNDOTBS1                             1090        759        331         70         30      32768
USERS                                   5          4          1         74         26      32768

7 rows selected.
```

**EDIT #2**

```
SQL> select segment_type,sum(bytes/power(1024,2)) as "Size MB" from dba_segments where tablespace_name='APP01' group by segment_type;
SEGMENT_TYPE          Size MB
------------------ ----------
LOBINDEX          92,5625
LOBSEGMENT        31702,5625
TABLE             1857
INDEX             1241,125
```

Answer (score 1):

The freespace is not given back to the OS but it doesn't mean you don't have free space in your database. You have to look at the tablespace usage, a tablespace is a logical space where you data resides, if you deleted everything in your tablespace you may be able te reclaim space at the OS level by resizing your datafiles.

Here is a script you can use to check your tablespace usage:

https://www.dba-scripts.com/scripts/administration/tablespace-usage-script/

You can use this report te verify how much space you can reclaim at os level by resizing your database datafiles:

https://www.dba-scripts.com/scripts/administration/datafile-space-reclaimable/

Comment: I have edited my question with output of the query. I am pretty sure I have more than 27MB remaining :) And I am not interested in reclaiming that space back to the OS. I am interested in keeping an eye on what's the current database's status space-wise

Comment: can you execute the following query:

select segment_type,sum(bytes/power(1024,2)) as "Size MB" from dba_segments where tablespace_name='APP01'
group by segment_type;

Comment: see edit #2. Pasted output there as it's multiline data

Comment: SO you have data in your tablespace, your app has not deleted the data correctly.

Comment: I did not say I have deleted ALL the data. I deleted some of it (>50%) and restarted the load test. Does that mean 32 GB of BLOBS is already occuppying the DB?

Comment: Yes that's what it means, you can also add information to the prevous query to verify if the owner of the objects is really the load app you're using:

select owner, segment_name, segment_type,bytes/power(1024,2) as "Size MB" from dba_segments where tablespace_name='APP01';

Comment: Nope, that can't be it. I've just had a similar issue on customer's database and configured the app to delete as many records as it can. `sum(DBMS_LOB.getlength(blobs.data)/1024/1024)` claims blobs usage has dropped from 60GB to 3GB and your `select segment_type` query still says that blobs occupy the same 61GB of tablespace as before mass-removal of data...

Answer (score 0):

#### Used and free space by tablespaces

```
SELECT tablespace_name,
       size_mb,
       free_mb,
       max_size_mb,
       max_free_mb,
       TRUNC((max_free_mb/max_size_mb) * 100) AS free_pct,
       RPAD(' '|| RPAD('X',ROUND((max_size_mb-max_free_mb)/max_size_mb*10,0), 'X'),11,'-') AS used_pct
FROM   (
        SELECT a.tablespace_name,
               b.size_mb,
               a.free_mb,
               b.max_size_mb,
               a.free_mb + (b.max_size_mb - b.size_mb) AS max_free_mb
        FROM   (SELECT tablespace_name,
                       TRUNC(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024) AS free_mb
                FROM   dba_free_space
                GROUP BY tablespace_name) a,
               (SELECT tablespace_name,
                       TRUNC(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024) AS size_mb,
                       TRUNC(SUM(GREATEST(bytes,maxbytes))/1024/1024) AS max_size_mb
                FROM   dba_data_files
                GROUP BY tablespace_name) b
        WHERE  a.tablespace_name = b.tablespace_name
       )
ORDER BY size_mb desc;
```

#### Used and free space by Oracle ASM disk groups

```
SELECT name, free_mb, total_mb, round(free_mb/total_mb*100) as pct_free FROM v$asm_diskgroup order by TOTAL_MB desc;
```